# Disk Space Requirements

Tags: windows, installation, disk-space, requirements

I want to know the minimum space requirement for each version of Windows (XP-7)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/sysreqs/pro.mspx

Windows XP:

- 300 megahertz or higher processor
  clock speed recommended; 233 MHz
  minimum required
- 128 megabytes (MB) of RAM or higher
  recommended (64 MB minimum supported;
  may limit performance and some
  features)
- 1.5 gigabytes (GB) of available hard disk space

From http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/get/system-requirements.aspx

Windows 7:

- 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster 32-bit
  (x86) or 64-bit (x64) processor.
- 1 gigabyte (GB) RAM (32-bit) or 2 GB
  RAM (64-bit).
- 16 GB available hard disk space (32-bit) or 20 GB
  (64-bit).

Comment: I think the min. RAM for Windows XP grew with SP3. But nevertheless you should understand these requirements just like the "maximum battery lifetime" of notebooks: They are only true as long as you don't actually use the system.

Answer (score 0):

Just be aware that the minimum stated for XP is really the MINIMUM!  Don't expect to put XP on a system with a 1.5 GB disk and 64 MB RAM and be able to run programs with anything like reasonable speed.  Do expect your disk to show constant activity (thrashing).

With Win7 you can actually run interesting things in 1 GB RAM as long as you can get it loaded on the disk ok.  Not sure how tight 16 GB would make it.

Comment: This should have been a comment rather then an answer.

Comment: probably right - feel free to move it